# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Tags: python, list, append

```
def convBin():
    cont = []
    rest = []
    dev = []
    decimal = []

    print("Ingrese el valor a convertir: ")
    valor = ast.literal_eval(input())

    if isinstance(valor, int):
        while valor > 0:
                z = valor // 2
            resto = valor%2
            valor = valor // 2
            cont.append(z)
            rest.append(resto)

        cont.reverse()
        rest.reverse()

        dev.append(cont[0])

        x = 0
        while x <= (len(rest) - 1):
            dev.append(rest[x])
            x += 1

        print(" ")
        print("Lista de devoluciones: ")
        print(dev)
        print("")

    elif isinstance(valor, float):
        a = valor // 1
        b = valor % 1

        while a > 0:
            z = a // 2
            resto = a%2
            a = a // 2
            cont.append(z)
            rest.append(resto)

        cont.reverse()
        rest.pop()

        dev.append(cont[1])

        for i in rest:
            dev.append(rest[i])

        print("Inserte el número de error minimo")
        num = input()

        while num > 0:
            dec = b * 1
            dec2 = dec//1
            dec %= 1        
            decimal.append(dec2)


        print("Parte entera: ")
        print(dev)
        print("Parte decimal:")
        print(num)

    else:
        print("Ha aparecido un error")
```

Its shows me an error that i can´t append a float into a list.

After asking you a number, it controls which type of number is it. When it is an int, it doesn´t have any problem. But when it´s a float, it says that it can´t add a float into a list where it´s saved the numbers of the operations made before.

Can someone explain it to me why I can´t append floats into a list or how can I solve the problem?

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "Converter.py", line 169, in
>    convBin(); File "Converter.py", line 53, in convBin
>   dev.append(rest[i]) TypeError: list indices must be integers or
>   slices, not float

Thanks.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: valor = ast.literal_eval(input())

Comment: What was typed as input?  `18`? `18.`? `18.89`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this loop? `for i in rest:
            dev.append(rest[i])`  Are you trying append every item in `rest` to the end of `dev`?  `rest` contains the results of your `resto` calculations which when `valor` is a float will be floats.  `some_float % 2` is a float.

Comment: in the input you can type whatever you want, if its int the code will do the first if, but if it´s float Will do another thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in rest` will give you the actual item in the list, and not index. From your code, it seems that you want to append the value. But actually, you are treating the value as index again, and trying to fetch it from the array.

```
for i in rest:
            dev.append(rest[i])
```

**Fix:**

Just change above to:

```
dev.extend(rest)
```

But this code, takes a value from rest, then again uses that value as an index, and if that value `i` turns out to be a `float`, it throws an exception.

You haven't mentioned which line gives you this error. But I think it must be this one. It might give many other unexpected errors like `array out of bound`, etc

This is the error I get, if I run your code for valor = 18.5

https://ideone.com/HGagLb

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./prog.py", line 71, in
>      File "./prog.py", line 51, in convBin TypeError: list
>   indices must be integers or slices, not float

Difference between the above example, and the one below(from your code, where you handle `int`):

```
x = 0
while x <= (len(rest) - 1):
    dev.append(rest[x])
    x += 1
```

is that, in the first case, i is actually the item(int or float) in the list rest, while in the later one, it's a valid index.

Comment: while-loop is bad.  `for i in range(len(rest)):dev.append(rest[i])` is better but non-idiomatic.  `for i in rest:dev.append(i)` is idiomatic Python.  But there's a better way: `dev.extend(rest)`.

Comment: I´m talking about the "elif", exactly this part of the code:
while x > 0:
  z = x // 16
  
  resto = x%16
  x = x // 16
  
  cont.append(z)
  rest.append(resto)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I copied the while loop example from OP's code, just to show the difference of handling index in `while` & `for`(each) loop. Obviously, dev.extend(rest) would be the best way to do this.

Comment: @Lunargenta: You mean you are getting the mentioned exception in this part?

while x > 0: z = x // 16 resto = x%16 x = x // 16 cont.append(z) rest.append(resto) 

That's odd. Because I can't see anything wrong with that code. (but, line 51 surely gives the error you mentioned)

https://ideone.com/HGagLb (check here)

Btw, are you using python 2 or python 3?

Comment: Python 3. The error jumps when it tries to append the float into a list.

Comment: Can you also add the error's stack trace in the question?
This error comes when you try to use a float as an index in a list, as it says `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float`
(it just happens to be in the same line as append). There is certainly no problem in appending floats to any list.

But I doubt it would be originated from the lines you mentioned in comments here.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Converter.py", line 169, in <module>
        convBin();
      File "Converter.py", line 53, in convBin
        dev.append(rest[i])
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Comment: That's the line I have mentioned. `dev.append(rest[i]) `. That's the culprit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180904/discussion-between-tushar-and-lunargenta).

Comment: That would work, but as @StevenRumbalski pointed out, dev.extend(rest) will be a better option.